# Solving the minimum value for resistance

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the problem by using calculus- local maxima and minima ?(By first derivative test)
 I solved it but I can't find the local maximum and minimum points.

[image: my progress]

Comment: Maybe you should post your progress so far, so we can give you better feedback.

Comment: I posted up there.

Comment: Your link is asking for a Google sign-in.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: I changed it .Thanks for your response .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F'(x) > 0$ is wrong for the interval $\left( -\frac1{\sqrt{5}}, \frac1{\sqrt{5}}\right)$. Try plugging in $x = \frac1{10}$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

**Method $1$**

As you have mentioned, by setting the 1st-order derivative equal to zero we attain to two points $$x=\pm{1\over 2\sqrt 5}$$ Also $$f''(x)={10\over x^3}$$since for $x={1\over 2\sqrt 5}$ we have $f''(x)>0$ therefore **the point $\left({1\over 2\sqrt 5},20\sqrt 5\right)$ is a *local minimum***. Similarly **the point $\left(-{1\over 2\sqrt 5},-20\sqrt 5\right)$ is a *local maximum*.**

**Method $2$**

We have $$f(x)={5\over x}+100x=10\sqrt 5\left({1\over 2\sqrt 5x}+2\sqrt 5x\right)\ge 20\sqrt 5$$where the equality happens if and only if $x={1\over 2\sqrt 5}$. Similarly for $x=-{1\over 2\sqrt 5}$

Comment: Why we get a  local maximum point when f ''(X)<0 ?

Comment: In fact this follows directly from the Taylor expansion:$$f(x+x_0)=f(x)+f'(x)\cdot x_0+{1\over 2}x_0^2\cdot f''(x)+o(x_0^2)$$where $o(.)$ is the famous little-o notation. Also we should have $f'(x)=0$ in local maximum to conclude that.